# How to submit multiple forms with one button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a view where you can edit info about all the Users at once. Here's how I made the view right now:

```
<% @users.each do |u| %>
  <%= render 'set_days_row', user: u %>
<% end %>
```

And here's 'set_days_row':

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <span><%= user.name %></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <%= form_for user do |f| %>
      <table class="days-table">
        <tr>
          <td>M</td>
          <td>Tu</td>
          <td>W</td>
          <td>Th</td>
          <td>F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><%= f.check_box :monday %></td>
          <td><%= f.check_box :tuesday %></td>
          <td><%= f.check_box :wednesday %></td>
          <td><%= f.check_box :thursday %></td>
          <td><%= f.check_box :friday %></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that since there's multiple forms, I can't just make an f.submit button because it wouldn't submit all the form objects. How can I do this?

Comment: Make a new update_many action to handle this so they can all be in one form.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what I would include in the action?

Comment: There are two parts to this - 1) a form that submits an array of hashes.  Each hash will have a user_id along with the checkbox params.  and 2) an update_many action that will loop through the array param and update the users found by the id.